# Civievent Confirmation Url Exit Page

Tags: civievent

Hello is there a way I can have people redirected to a specific url after they register for an event.  It seems in the civi event registration I can only specify text and email.  It seems this would be an important feature to track registrations through Google analytics.  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Happy CiviDay (well in NZ it is)

take a look at the [Front End Page Options](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.frontendpageoptions) extension that Fuzion developed previously.

Note the requirement for the [Entity Setting](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.entitysetting) extension

Let us know how you get on and which Civi version you try it with.